# Virgin trains advance ticket refund

Tags: uk, trains, tickets, london, refunds

I purchased an advance train ticket from virgin train from Manchester Piccadilly to Heathrow airport but I had to needed to travel through London Euston.

I requested for a refund of my previous ticket, got a mail from Virgin trains that I will get a refund in 5 working days. 
I purchased another ticket for London Euston route but when I didn't get a refund, I went through their app to find a way to contact them and I found out that Advance tickets are non refundable.

I requested for a refund and got a reply that I will be refunded instead of telling me that my ticket is non refundable. I purchased this ticket for 110 pounds and I am a tourist.

Is there anything I can do about this?[image]

Comment: What exactly did the email say? Can you post the text (with personal information blanked out)? Virgin trains from Manchester usually go into Euston, why did you need to change your ticket?

Comment: It looks as though the mail was sent before they had seen the ticket. Maybe they were confused about what sort of ticket the OP was asking to refund.

Answer (score 4):

Advance tickets are indeed non-refundable; this should have been made clear when you were sold the ticket. The date and time on an Advance ticket CAN be changed prior to travel (usually for a fee), but not the destination.

However, I echo the confusion of others about why you needed to buy a new ticket — your route from Manchester to Heathrow will likely have taken you via Euston, and while technically you're not allowed to stop short on an advance ticket, there's absolutely no way anyone could tell in this particular case since you would usually exit Euston Station to catch the tube towards Heathrow anyway!

As to why you were sent that email — well, without seeing the actual text of the email I can only imagine it was a mistake on the part of the customer services. They're only human after all. Perhaps if you explain the situation to them as you have done here they'll refund you as a goodwill gesture.